# Facebook dopamine kick - any proof?

Tags: social-networks, dopamine

A lot of people are writing that Facebook and other social media sites cause users to be addicted by serving up well timed dopamine kicks in response to interactions. I was searching for any sort of formal proof for this claim like a study of some sort but havent found anything. Is such a claim even provable?

Comment: They are combining what is known about the neurobiology of addictive behaviors and applying it to evidence for behavioral addition with social media, not literally measuring dopamine release during social media use. The "dopamine kick" description is quite simplified and a bit older thinking but still roughly applies.